# Windows SMTP Server with Server 2008 and PHP

Tags: php, iis, smtp, windows-server-2008

For some reason the iis smtp server and php are not communicating properly.  I have verified that the smtp is working by telneting to it and doing the mail commands and I'm able to receive an email.  In addition, I followed this link http://support.microsoft.com/?id=297700 and was able to receive an email.  But whenever I try to send email from PHP nothing happens.  What makes this even crazier is there are no smtp logs being written.  The log files should be located at c:\windows\system32\logfiles\smtpsvc1 but the smtpsvc1 folder does not exist and there are no email messages in the drop, pickup, queue, or badmail folders under mailroot.

I'm not really sure why no logs exist for this.  I gave the Network Service user permission to that logfiles folder but to no avail.  So I guess the gist of my question is how can I make PHP and iis smtp send email.

I have the smtp configured to send email to a remote MailEnable server **not** exchange. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Not really a direct answer, but you know that by default SMTP logging is not on and you need to enable it via IIS manager.  So, you won't get any logs until you do so.  You will be able to tell if logging is enabled, as SMTP startup/initialization will generate log entries, regardless to any other activities.  If your log file is blank, SMTP is not running.

Answer (score 0):

That test only applies to 2000, at least that what the papers says.
You should try [here](http://blogs.iis.net/bills/archive/2006/09/19/How-to-install-PHP-on-IIS7-_2800_RC1_2900_.aspx)